# Did hats just go quantum?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

I was browsing the review queues, when all of a sudden I see this -

[image]

So the guy at the yellow shirt and the froggy thing (sorry, they went away too fast for me to catch their names), are obviously wearing a hat that is not there at the next frame. A hat that is no more. Gone with the wind. Poof. One might say that the hat is in superposition of being a hat and no hat at the same time. Schrödingers' hat.

Could this be a fearful bug or are hats trying to fool with our minds? Am I being driven crazy by lust for hats? Or perhaps people just like to take their hats off for specific review queues?

Comment: Hrm, except that some do. I don't see your problem reproduced, now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Hm. Waited for someone to pop from the left, he was hatless, clicked to open his profile in a new tab - he's wearing a hat. Switched back to the queues - now it's there as well..

Comment: The hats are indeed slow to load for some of these. They *do* appear after a while.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, don't know why I didn't think of that. Maybe I should loosen my hat a bit to let more blood flow :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had forgotten that the recent reviewers are updated in realtime, so this wasn't handled. It is now.